# Reload data tableView from JSON

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a problem with reload data in tableView in my simple swift app for iOS.

If I for the first time enter the city name into the cityTextField and press the getDataButton, so the data displays correctly, but *If I enter the new city name into cityTextField and press button,* **so data are still the same like for the first city**.

ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate {

var arrDict :NSMutableArray=[]

@IBOutlet weak var cityTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var weatherTableView: UITableView!


@IBAction func getDataButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    weatherDataSource("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" + cityTextField.text! + "&appid=<app id>")

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func weatherDataSource(urlString: String) {

    let urlUTF = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let url = NSURL(string: urlUTF!)

        let query = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { ()
            self.loadDataWeather(data!)
            self.weatherTableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
        query.resume()
}


func loadDataWeather(dataPocasi: NSData){

    do {
        if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataPocasi, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
            print(json)

            for var i = 0 ; i < (json.valueForKey("list") as! NSArray).count ; i++
            {
                arrDict.addObject((json.valueForKey("list") as! NSArray) .objectAtIndex(i))
            }
        }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return arrDict.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell : TableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! TableViewCell

    if(cell == nil)

    {
        cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Cell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! TableViewCell;
    }
    let strTitle : NSNumber=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("dt") as! NSNumber
    let epocTime = NSTimeInterval(strTitle)
    let myDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:  epocTime)
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(myDate)
    cell.dayLabel.text=dateString

    let strDescription : NSDictionary=arrDict[indexPath.row] .objectForKey("main") as! NSDictionary
    if let bla = strDescription["temp"]{
        cell.tempLabel.text=bla.stringValue
    }
    return cell as TableViewCell
}

}
```

TableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
@IBOutlet weak var dayLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tempLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Comment: have you considered clearing your datasource array before loading new ones?

Comment: yes try empty arrDict in loadDataWeather

Comment: No, I haven't. I'd like to try, but I don't know how. I am amateur in programming. This is only term project to the college and this is my the first app

Comment: check whether getting any data for the new city entered. and also debug line by line to get to know that data source has changed and called reload table .

Comment: I had checked and debug the code and found that the URL which you had mentioned in the code getting the HTML response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not instantiating your tableView delegate. Make sure you call `self.weatherTableView.delegate = self` inside `viewDidLoad()`.

Also, you should create a new arrDict every time you load your data. `self.arrDict = []`.

In case the above ajustments dont work you should get some time debugging it. Make sure the second request is loading the data and, if so, your `self.weatherTableView.reloadData()` might not being called. You could try moving it to `loadDataWeather()`.

Comment: THX adolfosrs. For the first time I don't use your advice correct. But now is everything alright. Thank very match

Comment: You welcome. So what about setting my answer as the correct one and a vote up? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can reload tableview in "loadDataWether()" function.

Like,

```
func loadDataWeather(dataPocasi: NSData){

    do {
        if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataPocasi, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
            print(json)

            for var i = 0 ; i < (json.valueForKey("list") as! NSArray).count ; i++
            {
                arrDict.addObject((json.valueForKey("list") as! NSArray) .objectAtIndex(i))
            }
        }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    self.weatherTableView.reloadData()
}
```